# amforms: display form field

Tags: templating, fieldtypes, plugin-amforms

I'm trying to output an amform in a template that has been selected from a Form field. From the [amform docs](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms#simple-field-tag), it says:

```
{{ craft.amForms.displayForm('formHandle') }}
```

My matrix fieldname is called *myFormField*:

[image]

so:

```
{{ craft.amForms.displayForm('{{block.myFormField}}') }}
```

But it doesn't look like craft is parsing *{{block.myFormField}}*:

```
No form exists with the handle “{{block.myFormField}}”.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
{% if block.myFormField|length %}
    {{ block.myFormField.first().displayForm() }}
{% endif %}
```